# Node JS Express - Send Back a Response After Ajax Post To Node Route

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, routes, http-proxy

I'm using Node JS as a proxy server. In JavaScript, after hitting a button, I'm sending an ajax post to one of my routes. Here's the ajax post:

```
var requestData = {myData: blablaa,....};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
    url: '/my-route'
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log('returned data:', data);
});
```

And then my route looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.post('/refund-request', checkSession, function (req, res) {
    var urlEndpoint = "some.url.endpoint";
    request(urlEndpoint).pipe(res);
});
```

But I'm getting a 505 error on that.

In my route, how do I properly send back a response (like I would get if posting to an actual url)?

Comment: Where you defined  `refundUrl` and what it has the values?

Comment: add your app.js file, from where '/my-route' is getting routed. Incomplete information.

Comment: req.status(200).json({ msg: "some text"});